# NSXmlparser's delegate doesn't work?

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing, delegates, nsxmlparser

XMLParser file is working seperately but when I put it to my project I do not face any error but I cannot take data from URL. I guess , my setDelegate is not working.my xmlpar and print functions are working but the others aren't working.ı dont know what the matter is?can anyone help me??

my .h file

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestttxmlViewController : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>{
    NSXMLParser * pars;
    NSString * durum;
    NSMutableArray *arr;
}
-(void)print;
-(void)xmlpar;
@end
```

-->my .m file

```
  #import "TestttxmlViewController.h"
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self xmlpar];
}


-(void)xmlpar{
    arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSURL * url =[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://www.milliyet.com.tr/D/rss/rss/Rss_36.xml"];
    pars=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    durum=[[NSString alloc]init];
    [pars setDelegate:self];
    [pars parse];
    [self print];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict  {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        durum=elementName;
    }
}
-(void)print{
    NSLog(@"%@",arr);
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    durum=@"";

}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string  
{
    if ([durum isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [arr addObject:string];
    }
   }

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a wild guess since I have not used `NSXMLParser` but I would think that it parses in a background thread. That would mean that it might not finish parsing yet, and you already call a method to print the contents of `arr`.

```
-(void)xmlpar{
    //..
    [pars parse];
    [self print];
}
```

try calling `print` method in a delegate method that is called when parsing is finished, if such exists.

**EDIT**

After looking through the docs try calling print in `parserDidEndDocument` method

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    [self print];
}
```

Comment: ı tried this.but it still is not working. my functions (didStartElement,didEndElement,foundCharacters) aren't working.ı thing my proplem is setdelegate ??